# How to make flex-grow act not greedy?

Tags: css, flexbox

[image: illustration]

Markup:

```
<div class="playground">
  <div class="red">
    <div class="child">I don't need all this space, but my parents are greddy. : (</div>
  </div>
  <div class="blue">I want to grow big!</div>
</div>
```

Stylesheet:

```
.playground {
  width: 500px; height: 500px; background: #ccc; display: flex; flex-direction: column;
}

.red,
.blue {
  width: 100%;
}

.red {
  flex: 1; background: rgba(255,0,0,.5);

  .child {
    background: rgba(255,255,255,.5); padding: 10px; margin: 10px;
  }
}

.blue {
  background: rgba(0,0,255,.5); min-height: 100px; max-height: 300px;
}
```

[http://jsbin.com/waset/1/](http://jsbin.com/waset/3/)

In the above example,

- **Red** container is set to use all available space (`flex-grow`).
- **Red** container is sharing space with **blue**.
- **Blue** has `max-height: 300px`.
- **Red** content is not taking all of the height. If **red** wasn't greedy, it would give away extra 200px to **blue**.

How to make red not greedy?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `flex:1;` to .blue
By the way, you misspelled `width` in `.red,.blue`

Comment: That won't work as then **blue** will become greedy instead, http://jsbin.com/waset/4/ and ignore `min-height`.

Comment: What if you replaced `min-height` and `max-height` with `height`, then modify the size of `.blue` with JavaScript? Something like:  `var bluebox = document.querySelector(".blue");  
bluebox.onclick=function(){resize.style.height = "100px";};`

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you can use `flex-grow` on both `.red` and `.blue` and give blue a very large value.  Using `flex-grow` instead of the `flex` shorthand will default `flex-basis` to `auto`.  As a result, the `flex-basis` will be based on the content and then only after the initial content is taken into consideration will leftover space be distributed.

The very large value on `.blue` will cause it to consume nearly all remaining space up until it reaches its max-width.

```
.red {
    flex-grow: 1;
    background: rgba(255, 0, 0, .5);

    .child {
        background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
        padding: 10px 10px;
        margin: 10px;
    }
}

.blue {
    flex-grow: 999;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 255, .5);
    min-height: 100px;
    max-height: 300px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for? I can't remember where I learned this technique, but I will post credits when I come across the Website again. I created two flexboxes, a blue and red, and each one expands in size when you hover over them. Hope this helps.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>

       <style>
       .flx
       {
          width: 400px;
          height: 200px;
          font: 12px auto;

          display: -webkit-flex;
          -webkit-flex-direction: column;
          display: flex;
          flex-direction: column;
       }

       .flx > div
       {
          -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
          flex: 1 1 auto;
          width: 50px;

          -webkit-transition: width 0.2s ease-out; /*adjust speed of size change*/
  transition: width 0.2s ease-out;

       }
       .flx > div:nth-child(1){ background : red; }
       .flx > div:nth-child(2){ background : blue; }
       .flx > div:hover    /*adjust size when you hover*/
       {

            width: 200px;
       }
       </style>  

     </head>
     <body>
      <div class="flx">
        <div>red box</div>
        <div>blue box</div>
      </div>
     </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Oh, and I put all my text in a single div class, which I normally reference on a separate css, but which are imbedded in the main html here for demonstration.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can set `flex: 1;` instead of `flex-grow` to `.red` and `.blue`. This works in Facebook's Yoga Layout.